# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'GetLatdlngd' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I did a code to get Address from postal code. I wrote a code like below

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.handleInput=this.handleInput.bind(this);
    this.GetpostalAddress=this.GetpostalAddress.bind(this);
    this.GetLatdlngd=this.GetLatdlngd.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAl_I8Rp3zLc4ZN8gBLRTmOjwacWAHSk4Y";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);    
}

handleInput(e)
{
    var PostalCode=e.target.value;
    var latitude=0;
    var longitude=0;
    var Placeid='';
    var latlng =0;
    if(PostalCode.length==6)
    {
        this.GetpostalAddress(PostalCode,function(Address){
            alert(Address);
            this.GetLatdlngd(Address,function(){
            });

        });
    }
}

GetpostalAddress(PostalCode,callback)
{
    var HotelName='Hotel ABC';
    var City='';
    var State='';
    var Country='';
    var Address='';
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': PostalCode }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(results));
            City=results[0].address_components[1].long_name;
            State=results[0].address_components[3].long_name;
            Country=results[0].address_components[4].long_name;
            Address=HotelName+','+City+','+State+','+Country;
            callback(Address);
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}

GetLatdlngd(Address,callback)
{
    alert('inlat='+Address);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'address': Address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var lattitude=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude=results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            //alert(JSON.stringify(results));`enter code here`
            alert(lattitude,longitude);
            callback();
        }
    });
    //
}
```

but while calling second function its throwing error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'GetLatdlngd' of undefined

Can anybody tell me why this error is occurring`

Comment: Do you have a class for which you have defined the constructor?

Comment: After your change currently my code looks like below:

Comment: please review edited code

Answer (score 0):

That is because `GetLatdlngd` is defined on `window` but you are expecting it in `GetpostalAddress`.

This should work fine.

After your change currently my code looks like below:

```
class PropertyPostalCode extends BaseComponent{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);      
        this.handleInput=this.handleInput.bind(this);
        this.GetpostalAddress=this.GetpostalAddress.bind(this);
        this.GetLatdlngd=this.GetLatdlngd.bind(this);

    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAl_I8Rp3zLc4ZN8gBLRTmOjwacWAHSk4Y";
        script.async = true;

        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    handleInput(e)
    {
        var PostalCode=e.target.value;
        var latitude=0;
        var longitude=0;
        var Placeid='';
        var latlng =0;
        if(PostalCode.length==6)
        {
            this.GetpostalAddress(PostalCode,function(Address){
                alert(Address);
                GetLatdlngd(Address,function(){
                });

            });

        }
    }

    GetpostalAddress(PostalCode,callback)
    {
        var HotelName='Hotel ABC';
        var City='';
        var State='';
        var Country='';
        var Address='';
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': PostalCode }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(results));
                City=results[0].address_components[1].long_name;
                State=results[0].address_components[3].long_name;
                Country=results[0].address_components[4].long_name;
                Address=HotelName+','+City+','+State+','+Country;
                callback(Address);
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });

    }

    GetLatdlngd(Address,callback)
    {
        alert('inlat='+Address);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({'address': Address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var lattitude=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude=results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                //alert(JSON.stringify(results));`enter code here`
                alert(lattitude,longitude);
                callback();
            }
        });
        //
    }
```

Comment: I didn't get where did you change the code to run fine.Could you please mark where did the change is exactly needed?

Comment: I tried to run with your  change in code.but still its throwing error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: GetLatdlngd is not defined'.